# CMIS Changelog move event: From where to where?

Tags: cmis

A [CMIS server](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html) can generate a ChangeLog event when a document has been moved from a folder to another.

The ChangeLog event contains:

- the nature of the change, for instance `updated`,
- optional properties *(because I want to be compatible with any CMIS server, I can't rely on them)*,
- the identifier of the document **OR** the identifier of the ***folder*** containing it:

> A repository MAY record events such as ﬁling/unﬁling/moving of documents as change events on the documents, their parent folder(s), or both the documents and the parent folders.
>
> *(CMIS 1.1 paragraph 2.1.15.1)*

**QUESTION**: In case the ChangeLog event only contains the identifier of the ***folder*** containing the moved document, is there a way to know where the document has been moved from/to?